# For loop inside block assignment?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Here's an elementary loop, which compiles fine when outside of an assignment block:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <p>{{item}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But when I place the loop inside of an [assignment block](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#block-assignments), like so

```
{% set stuff %}
  {% for item in items %}
    <p>{{item}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endset %}
```

I get `AssertionError: Tried to resolve a name to a reference that was unknown to the frame ('item')`.

The motivation for the question is that I am using macros to avoid code duplication. E.g., I have a number of divs with different fields. One of the divs contains a message to the user. In one (but only one) case, I would like to include a `<ul>` in this div, and so I would like to loop through the elements in a list, wrapping each of them in `<li>` tags, before passing the resulting html as an argument to the macro. Hence my question.

Is it possible to use a for loop inside of an assignment block? Or is there a better way of achieving the same thing?

Comment: why do you use it?

Comment: documentation doesn't show examples with `for`-loop inside  assignment block - so probably it is not possible to use it. And I don't know how it would be usefull to generate some HTML with values and later duplicate exactly the same HTML - because it will not work as template which will use different `items`

Comment: @furas I am using macros to avoid code duplication. E.g., I have a number of divs with different fields. One of the divs contains a message to the user. In one case, I would like to include a `<ul>` in this div, and so I would like to loop through the elements in a list, wrapping each of them in `<li>` tags, before passing it to the macro. Hence my question.

Comment: @msailor That information you gave to furas in the comment is really important. Put it in the question, so others, when answering your question, can point alternative ways to achieve the same goal.

Comment: It tested it directly with `jinja` and I don't get your error message. But `set` has one big drawback: it can't get different variables and it works only with `items`. You should put `for`-loop in `macro stuff(items)` and then you can use `stuff(main_items)`, `stuff(other_items)`

Comment: I found that your problem is only in the newest Jinja 3.x - [AssertionError: Tried to resolve a name to a reference that was unknown to the frame](https://github_com.jam.dev/pallets/jinja/issues/1427). Older versions works correctly. But still I think  you should use `macro`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [AssertionError: Tried to resolve a name to a reference that was unknown to the frame](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/1427) this problem is only in `Jinja2` versions `3.x`. Older versions `2.x` works correctly.

At this moment it needs to set variable before you use it in block. Maybe later they fix it.

```
{% set item = None %}

{% set stuff %}
  {% for item in items %}
    <p>{{item}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endset %}

{{ stuff }}
```

---

But `set` has one big drawback for me: it can't get arguments and it works only with `items`.
And it can't works if I set `{% set items = other_items %}`

I would rather put code in `macro` to use `stuff(main_items)`, `stuff(other_items)`, etc.

```
{% macro stuff(items) %}
  {% for item in items %}
    <p>{{item}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{{ stuff(main_items) }}

{{ stuff(other_items) }}
```

Minimal working code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<h1>SET</h1>

{% set item = None %}

{% set stuff_set %}
  {% for item in items %}
    <p>{{item}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endset %}

{{ stuff_set }}

<h1>MACRO</h1>

{% macro stuff_macro(items) %}
  {% for item in items %}
    <p>{{item}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{{ stuff_macro(main_items) }}
{{ stuff_macro(other_items) }}
''', items=['A', 'B', 'C'], main_items=[1,2,3], other_items=[4,5,6])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```

Comment: I will file an issue since it seems to be a bug. But thanks for the workaround!