# Jinja2 `set` block throwing errors

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to set a variable in jinja2 but I am getting errors. Here is my code:

```
genre_mac = """    
        {%- set sql -%} 
            insert into name (a,b,c) values
            {% for row in [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] -%}
                (
                {%- for column in row -%}
                    ?
                    {%- if not loop.last%},{%- endif %}
                {%- endfor -%}
                )
                {%- if not loop.last%},{%- endif %}
            {%- endfor -%}
        {%- endset -%}
    {{ sql }}
    
"""

print(
    Template(genre_mac).render()
)
```

When I run this, I get this error (it's a long one, just pasted the last few lines):

```
c:\python-3.8.2\lib\site-packages\jinja2\compiler.py in pop_assign_tracking(self, frame)
    811                 if idx:
    812                     self.write(", ")
--> 813                 ref = frame.symbols.ref(name)
    814                 self.write(f"{name!r}: {ref}")
    815             self.write("})")

c:\python-3.8.2\lib\site-packages\jinja2\idtracking.py in ref(self, name)
     78         rv = self.find_ref(name)
     79         if rv is None:
---> 80             raise AssertionError(
     81                 "Tried to resolve a name to a reference that was"
     82                 f" unknown to the frame ({name!r})"

AssertionError: Tried to resolve a name to a reference that was unknown to the frame ('row')
```

However, what's weird is that, when I remove the `{% set sql %}` and `{% endset %}`, I don't get any errors:

```
genre_mac = """    

            insert into name (a,b,c) values
            {% for row in [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] -%}
                (
                {%- for column in row -%}
                    ?
                    {%- if not loop.last%},{%- endif %}
                {%- endfor -%}
                )
                {%- if not loop.last%},{%- endif %}
            {%- endfor -%}

    
"""

print(
    Template(genre_mac).render( )
)
```

I get the results:

```
insert into name (a,b,c) values
            (?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?)
```

What is happening here? Thanks!

Comment: Your original code runs for me (Python 3.9.6, Jinja2 2.11.3) without any errors.

Comment: Is it a problem with my version then `Python 3.8.2 Jinja2==3.0.1`

Comment: Maybe! Try upgrading Jinja first and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I downgraded and it seemed to fix the problem. I think I'll stay with version 2.11.3. Thanks!

Comment: The issue is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67937075/for-loop-inside-block-assignment